# Sql select where a column has been set atleast once

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this table

```
**applications**

id  user_id  company_id  shortlisted
1   10       99          0
2   10       100         1
3   10       101         1
4   10       102         0
5   11       99          1
6   12       99          0
6   12       101         0
```

What I want is to select all users

- which have been shortlisted at-least once
- which have not been shortlisted at all

For the first case, i have the following query:

```
SELECT user_id 
  from applications 
 where shortlisted=1 
 Group 
  By user_id
```

and this gives me the expected result like below

```
**applications**

user_id  
10       
11
```

But I'm trying the following query for the second case and it returns me an empty set:

```
Select user_id 
  from applications as Application 
 where shortlisted=0 
   and NOT EXISTS(Select user_id from applications where user_id=Application.user_id and shortlisted=1)
```

What am i missing?

PS: Please ignore any typos as i typed them manually for this post.

Comment: Second query: Is this a typo? `Select user_id as Application from applications` should be `Select user_id from applications as Application`, right? You want a table alias for the comparision in the subquery.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, that is a typo. Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Hm, the fixed query should work in my opinion. `applications` columns should have precedence over `Application` columns when not using a qualifier in the subquery. However, you may want to use qualifiers for all columns just to make sure. `select user_id from applications a0 where shortlisted = 0 and not exists (select * from applications a1 where a1.user_id = a0.user_id and a1.shortlisted = 1)`.

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56b9df/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having` for both.

For the first:

```
select user_id
from applications 
group By user_id
having max(shortlisted) = 1;
```

For the second:

```
select user_id
from applications 
group By user_id
having max(shortlisted) = 0;
```

In all honesty, your version with the `where` is more efficient for the first query.  This is just to show how closely related the queries are.

Comment: Could you please briefly elaborate why my second query fails. I know it's the faulty subquery but it would be nice to know why it fails.

Answer (score 1):

To get both results in a single query simply use aggregation:

```
select user_id, max(shortlisted) as was_shortlisted
from applications 
group By user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query;

```
select user_id from table1 
group by user_id having MIN(shortlisted) = 1
```

This will give you to at least have `shortlisted = 1` condition and don't have `shortlisted = 0` records.

Comment: No, because you remove all rows with `shortlisted = 0` before aggregation.

Comment: Nice option but don't you think using the `IF/ELSE` would hurt the optimization efforts?